# 1838. Frequency of the Most Frequent Element leetcode C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, brute-force

I am trying LeetCode problem [1838. Frequency of the Most Frequent Element](https://leetcode.com/problems/frequency-of-the-most-frequent-element/):

> The **frequency** of an element is the number of times it occurs in an array.
>
> You are given an integer array `nums` and an integer `k`. In one operation, you can choose an index of `nums` and increment the element at that index by 1.
>
> Return *the **maximum possible frequency** of an element after performing **at most** `k` operations.*

I am getting a Wrong Answer error for a specific test case.

#### My code

```
int checkfreq(vector<int>nums,int k,int i)
{
    //int sz=nums.size();
    int counter=0;
    //int i=sz-1;
    int el=nums[i];
    while(k!=0 && i>0)
    {
        --i;
        while(nums[i]!=el && k>0 && i>=0)
        {
            ++nums[i];
            --k;
        }
    }
    counter=count(nums.begin(),nums.end(),el);
    return counter;
}


class Solution {
public:
    int maxFrequency(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        sort(nums.begin(),nums.end());
        vector<int> nums2=nums;
        auto distinct=unique(nums2.begin(),nums2.end());
        nums2.resize(distance(nums2.begin(),distinct));
        int xx=nums.size()-1;
        int counter=checkfreq(nums,k,xx);
        for(int i=nums2.size()-2;i>=0;--i)
        {
            --xx;
            int temp=checkfreq(nums,k,xx);
            if(temp>counter)
                counter=temp;
        }
   
        return counter;
        
    }
};
```

### Failing test case

#### Input

```
nums = [9968,9934,9996,9928,9934,9906,9971,9980,9931,9970,9928,9973,9930,9992,9930,9920,9927,9951,9939,9915,9963,9955,9955,9955,9933,9926,9987,9912,9942,9961,9988,9966,9906,9992,9938,9941,9987,9917,10000,9919,9945,9953,9994,9913,9983,9967,9996,9962,9982,9946,9924,9982,9910,9930,9990,9903,9987,9977,9927,9922,9970,9978,9925,9950,9988,9980,9991,9997,9920,9910,9957,9938,9928,9944,9995,9905,9937,9946,9953,9909,9979,9961,9986,9979,9996,9912,9906,9968,9926,10000,9922,9943,9982,9917,9920,9952,9908,10000,9914,9979,9932,9918,9996,9923,9929,9997,9901,9955,9976,9959,9995,9948,9994,9996,9939,9977,9977,9901,9939,9953,9902,9926,9993,9926,9906,9914,9911,9901,9912,9990,9922,9911,9907,9901,9998,9941,9950,9985,9935,9928,9909,9929,9963,9997,9977,9997,9938,9933,9925,9907,9976,9921,9957,9931,9925,9979,9935,9990,9910,9938,9947,9969,9989,9976,9900,9910,9967,9951,9984,9979,9916,9978,9961,9986,9945,9976,9980,9921,9975,9999,9922]
k = 1524
```

#### Output

Expected: 81

My code returns: 79

I tried to solve as many cases as I could. I realise this is a bruteforce approach, but don't understand why my code is giving the wrong answer.

My approach is to convert numbers from last into the specified number. I need to check these as we have to count how many maximum numbers we can convert. Then this is repeated for every number till second last number. This is basically what I was thinking while writing this code.

Comment: *am I getting WA* -- What is `WA`?  An abbreviation for the state of Washington in the USA?  Contrary to popular belief, many, if not most C++ programmers do not go to "competition" or similar websites, so those abbreviations you're using doesn't mean anything.  Do not use abbreviations when describing what the issue is.

Comment: *but I wanted to know what am I doing wrong* -- You wrote the code, you have the test case.  What debugging have you done to see where the code goes against your plan?  BTW, this problem can be solved in maybe 3 or 4 lines of code using `std::map`, or at the very least eliminate 90% of your code using `std::map`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie • https://www.quora.com/What-is-WA-RTE-CTE-and-TLE-on-CodeChef

Comment: @Grimshingamii `std::map<int, int> theMap; for (auto n : nums) ++theMap[n];` -- The map has all the unique numbers and their associated frequencies in those 3 lines of code.  What if your "brute force" method has no easy fix for it?  You might as well learn what the better data structure is to solve the problem (you even tagged `data-structures`).  Also, those competition websites ask questions where there is always a naive solution that never works when given extreme amounts of data in one or more test cases.  So you have no choice but to use a better approach, rather than brute force.

Comment: @Eljay -- I went to that quora link, and there was a link to [here](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-more-frustrating-wrong-answer-WA-or-time-limit-exceeded-TLE-Why).  Going by some of the responses, these competition websites are thought of as the be all and end all for a lot of these programmers.  SamV has a point, if I were to go by what some of those responses say.  It also will explain why StackOverflow gets so many questions from persons using those sites -- it seems to mean a lot in answering those site's random puzzles.

Comment: @Eljay -- Also [this link](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-true-that-if-you-dont-do-competitive-programming-you-are-not-a-programmer) and at least one response from someone in India sums up what we are seeing here on StackOverflow, and again, emphasizes SamV's point about hoping to land a job using these sites.  It seems that one CP programmer got a job at a firm, thus everyone believes that this is the fast path to fame and fortune.  Wow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the different output is that your `xx` index is only decreased one unit at each iteration of the `i` loop. But that loop is iterating for the number of *unique* elements, while `xx` is an index in the *original* vector. When there are many duplicates, that means `xx` is coming nowhere near the start of the vector and so it misses opportunities there.

You could fix that problem by replacing:

```
--xx;
```

...with:

```
--xx;
while (xx >= 0 && nums[xx] == nums[xx+1]) --xx;
if (xx < 0) break;
```

That will solve the issue you raise. You can also drop the `unique` call, and the `distinct`, `nums2` and `i` variables. The outer loop could just check that `xx > 0`.

### Efficiency is your next problem

Your algorithm is not as efficient as needed, and other tests with huge input data will time out.

Hint 1: `checkfreq`'s inner loop is incrementing `nums[i]` one unit at a time. Do you see a way to have it increase with a larger amount, so to avoid that inner loop?

Hint 2 (harder): `checkfreq` is often incrementing the same value in different calls -- even more so when `k` is large and the section of the vector that can be incremented is large. Can you think of a way to avoid that `checkfreq` needs to redo that much work in subsequent calls, and can only concentrate on what is *different* compared to what it had to calculate in the previous call?